# CSV Import to SQL Issues - text delimiter issues

Tags: sql, csv, delimiter

All:

I've experienced CSV import issues MANY times.  I have an extract from a client that's 1MM rows - the text fields (most of them anyway) have double-quote delimiters, but some do not (apologies for the small image, but please click to view larger version):
[image]

Also, there are numbers in this extract that have commas in them, and SQL identifies these as separate field values:
[image]

Clearly every data element should be in double-quotes (numeric or not), and at a minimum the numeric values should not be formatted with commas (i.e., 5,159 should be 5159).

Is there any hope of salvaging this file?  The last resort is to bother the client to re-run this data but export as TSV or something useful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The typical way to deal with commas which are really part of the data, and not the separator, is to escape those columns using something like double quotes (or any other character which is not being used as data).  So, you should go back to the source of this data, and fix it there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  Thank you, Tim - appreciate the quick response.  My fear with situations like this is running a script or some other method to manually "fix" the data (post export).  Best to do what you suggest.

Comment: Your data isn't completely readable, but basically in the general case to fix this you'd need to write some sort of rudimentary parser.  A lot of work, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and "SQL" (the language) does not "identify" CSV files at all. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`. Also: which tool do you use to import those files?